# Damage vs Maintenance

Tags: real-estate, michigan

In my community, we have an individual who, while building a house, brought in large amounts of heavy material which caused the road to fail. When confronted about the cost of repairs, he brought up that the HOA covenants state that maintenance costs must be split equally amongst the residents, and refused to pay.

What is the legal difference between damage and required maintenance?

In my view, this may be similar to a renter-landlord situation where the landlord is expected to maintain the property, but egregious damages warrant keeping a security deposit or beyond if the tenant caused more wear and tear than can be reasonably expected, and could be sued for that overrun.

Comment: It's quite possible that the HOA covenants are ambiguous in this case and you have a disagreement as to whether or not there was damage.  This is what the civil courts are for.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the building materials which allegedly caused the road to fail were significantly heavier than those customarily used to build other houses in the neighborhood (or houses in general)?

Comment: Normally this would be addressed in the governing documents of the HOA which often provide that damage as a result of the negligence of a member or the member's invitee is charged to the member. But, it depends upon what it says to some extent.